# Pytorch1.6 What is the actual learning rate during training?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, learning-rate

I'd like to know the actual learning rate during training, here is my code.

```
learning_rate = 0.001
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.MultiStepLR(optimizer, milestones=[1, 2], gamma=0.1)


def train(epoch):
    train_loss = 0

    for batch_idx, (input, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
        predict_label = net(input)
        loss = criterion(predict_label, target)
        train_loss += loss.item()

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        print(optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr'])

    scheduler.step()
    print(scheduler.state_dict()['_last_lr'])
    print(optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr'])
```

the output is 0.001, 0.0001, 0.0001. So what is the actual lr during optimizer.step()? 0.001 or 0.0001? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important part is here:

```
for batch_idx, (input, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
    ...

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    print(optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr']) #### CURRENT LEARNING RATE

scheduler.step() #step through learning rate
print(scheduler.state_dict()['_last_lr']) #### NEW LEARNING RATE
print(optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr']) #### NEW LEARNING RATE
```

Because you step your scheduler after your epoch, then the first epoch will have your initial value which is set to `0.001`. If you run for multiple epochs then it will continue to be annealed.